# RavenDB Query Documents with Property Removed

Tags: ravendb

In the RavenDB Studio, I can see 69 CustomVariableGroup documents. My query only returns 66 of them. After some digging, I see that the three docs that are *not* returned have the new class structure: a property was removed. Since I saved these three CustomVariableGroup documents, their structure is different from the other 66. Why though, when I query for all of them, do I only get the other 66 documents with the old structure?

Both my C# code, and my query in LinqPad, only return the 66. Here's the LinqPad query:

```
Session.Query<CustomVariableGroup>().Dump();  // returns 66 docs
```

But, if I do this, I can get one of the three documents that is missing from the above query:

```
Session.Query<CustomVariableGroup>().Where(x => x.Name == "Derating").Dump();
```

How can I get all 69 documents returned in one query?

** Edit: Index Info **

In the SQL tab of the LinqPad query (and in the Raven server output), the index looks like this:

Url: /indexes/dynamic/CustomVariableGroups?query=&start=0&pageSize=128&aggregation=None

I don't see that index in Raven Studio, presumably because it's dynamic.

** Edit 2: This HACK works **

If I do this, I get all 69 documents:

```
Session.Query<CustomVariableGroup>().Where(x => x.Name != string.Empty).Dump();
```

My guess is that Raven must be using an old index that only gets documents that still contain that deleted column. I somehow need to use a new/different index...

Interestingly, this does not work; it only returns 66:

```
Session.Query<CustomVariableGroup>().Where(x => x.Id != string.Empty).Dump();
```

** Edit 3: This HACK works as well **

```
Session.Advanced.LuceneQuery<CustomVariableGroup>("Raven/DocumentsByEntityName").Where("Tag:CustomVariableGroups").Dump();
```

Comment: I would try to make your own Map (index) and see if you get the same results. You might also want to post this question to the RavenDB Google Group Ayende / team monitor that group and will most likely respond back quickly.  If you find the answer post it back here would you? I would like to know what you find...I am still really new myself to RavenDB.

Comment: I did try an index, but still only got the 66 documents. If I don't get an answer here soon, I'll try the google group. And yes, I'll post any answer here, too. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An index, with the old property, had to be removed.

** Before ** This didn't work (only returned 66 of the 69 documents):

```
Session.Query<CustomVariableGroup>().Dump();
```

**** Fix ** Delete index that used the old property that was deleted from my C# class:**

In Raven Studio, I deleted this index: Auto/CustomVariableGroups/ByApplicationId

** After ** This same query now returns all 69 documents:

```
Session.Query<CustomVariableGroup>().Dump();
```

Now, I'm not sure why these queries would use that index. I'm querying for all CustomVariableGroup documents, and not ByApplicationId. However, removing that index fixed it. I'm sure someone else can explain why.

Comment: When you are using dynamic queries, we select a matching index. If you had an index that only used that property, it might have been selected, and then you wouldn't get the items without that property

Comment: Thank you, sir. Your comment confirms that this is the correct answer.

Comment: How are we supposed to find out that an index became invalid?

Answer (score 0):

What do the indexes look like? Did you manually create the indexes or were they dynamically created? Just wondering if that is the cause of the issue based on your comments above that there was a structure change to the object.

--S

Comment: See my ** Edit ** in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be a stale index.. if its not returning all the results you expect.

You could use

.Customize(x=>x.WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfLastWrite())