# RavenDB - LINQ - Count() discrepancies

Tags: linq, nosql, ravendb, linqpad

I am seeing  conflicting results using LINQ queries in RavenDB, I am curious as to how the .Count() works exactly.

Query 1:

```
Session.Query<thisEntity>
.Count()
```

> Result : 205 - meaning I have 205 documents of thisEntity.

Query 2:

```
Session.Query<thisEntity>
.Take(210)
.Dump()
```

> Result : In LINQ pad this query shows the dump of 197 documents only. I was expecting to see 205 documents

Query 3:

```
Session.Query<thisEntity>
.Distinct()
.Count()
```

> Result : 197 - Might mean that there are 197 unique documents and the
>   rest 8 of them are duplicates. This is another thing, there is no way duplicates can be created in our RavenDB instance.

My question: How can I get a dump of those 8 supposedly existing duplicates so I can check clearly what they are. Right now, Count gives me 205, dump gives me only 197. I want to query the db for those extra 8 duplicates.

Comment: I thing this is more to do with the fact that internally RavenDB does different things when you issue a query with/without a page size. It may be a bug, can you post a full code sample that shows the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Are the documents exactly the same, or are some older versions of the object with missing properties? If so, you may be experiencing the same issue [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446925/ravendb-query-documents-with-property-removed).

Comment: The documents are exactly the same. The structure has not changed.